# Pivot Filter using excluding values, (or including more values in future)

Tags: excel, filter, pivot-table

In pivot filters I would like to exclude some values and show the rest.

For example (please refer to the image) in the given data, I want my pivot to show data for **All regions except Europe, Africa & Australia**.  Which is achieved now by removing the tick marks for those items.

But in some months the data gets **East** region, and the pivot is excluding that as well. Any ways to resolve this.

Can this be solved without including additional columns as the data comes from a different source and I have very less influence to change that.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Right Click on the Filer -> Field Settings -> Include New Items in manual filter